# How to skip/disregard files with names that use wide characters using std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, wstring, std-filesystem

I am iterating through a large set of nested directories searching for files of some extension, say ".foo" using code like the following:

```cpp
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator("<some directory>")) {
        if (entry.path().extension() == ".foo") {
            std::cout << entry.path().string() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

however the above throws on files with names that use unicode/wide characters. I know I can fix the problem in the little program above by using wstring everywhere i.e. `std::wcout << entry.path().wstring() << std::endl;` but what I actually need to do in my real program is skip such files. Right now I am catching the exception in the body of the for-loop and doing nothing in that case but am wondering if there is a more direct approach.

In Windows/Visual Studio the specific exception being thrown is

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte
> code page.

How do I test for such filenames using standard C++?

Comment: `std::string path = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>(). to_bytes(entry.path().wstring());` is what I use to convert it to UTF8.. Not sure how to check if it is wide or not. `codecvt_utf8` is deprecated in C++17 afaik..

Comment: @Brandon "*Not sure how to check if it is wide or not*" - check if the resulting UTF-8 string contains any non-ASCII characters > 0x7F.

Comment: At which point is the exception actually occurring? When retrieving the entry's `path()`, the path's `extension()`, or the path's `string()`? What is the actual exception that is being thrown? What does it say?

Comment: It occurs turning the path into a string. This is on visual studio. I don’t have the text of the actual exception but it was thrown in visual studio’s implementation of a narrowing conversion saying basically that there are characters for which narrowing cannot be done — I think the file name has East Asian characters in it.

Comment: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page."

Comment: @jwezorek Makes sense then, since `path::string()` will try to encode the path into the calling user's default ANSI locale, which may not be able to handle all of the Unicode characters in the path.  Use `path::wstring()`, `path::u16string()`, `path::u32string()`, or `path:u8string()` to avoid such lossy ANSI conversions, then you wouldn't have to ignore files with non-ASCII characters. Or, you can simply not convert the `path` to a string at all (for instance, `path` has an overload for `operator<<`, ie `std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;`).

Comment: the reason i have to skip is because i am going to be calling into library functions that take `const char*` filenames, but it doesnt matter ... im assembling a corpus of certain types of files and skipping a few out of thousands is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode characters have values `> 0x7f`, so you could do something like this:

```
bool is_wide = false;
for (auto ch : entry.path().wstring())
{
    if (ch > 0x7f)
    {
        is_wide = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!is_wide)
    std::cout << entry.path().string() << std::endl;
```